# Cannot nest Text inside View in React Native FlatList

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm having this trouble while using React Native `FlatList` recently. All I want to do is display a calendar block using `FlatList`. Here is my code

`Calendar.js` :

```js
import {View , Text, StyleSheet, FlatList} from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import {DayItem} from './DayItem'


export const Calendar = () => {
    const DayList = Array.of(42);
    for(i=0;i<42;i++){
        DayList[i] = i;
    }
    const element = DayList.map(item => (<DayItem number = {item}></DayItem>) )
    return(
        <View style = {{flex:3, borderStyle: 'solid' , borderTopWidth:0.5,
                        borderBottomWidth:0.5, alignItems:'center'}}>
            <View style = {{flex:1,borderStyle: 'solid', borderColor: 'blue', borderWidth : 1, 
                            marginTop:5, marginBottom:2, width:370, alignItems:'stretch'}}>
                <View style = {{ flex:1, borderStyle: 'solid', borderBottomWidth: 1,
                               flexDirection:'row', borderBottomColor: 'red', justifyContent: 'space-between',
                                marginTop:3}}>
                    <Text style = {style.textWeek}>Mon</Text>
                    <Text style = {style.textWeek}>Tue</Text>
                    <Text style = {style.textWeek}>Wed</Text>
                    <Text style = {style.textWeek}>Thu</Text>
                    <Text style = {style.textWeek}>Fri</Text>
                    <Text style = {style.textWeek}>Sat</Text>
                    <Text style = {style.textWeek}>Sun</Text>
                </View>
                <View style = {{flex:14, borderStyle: 'solid', borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'yellow',
                                }}>
                    <FlatList data = {element} renderItem = {renderDayItem} keyExtractor = {keyExtract}
                                 numColumns ={numColumns} />

                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
const numColumns = 7

const renderDayItem = ({item})=> (
    <DayItem number = {item}></DayItem>
)

const keyExtract = (item) => item

const style = StyleSheet.create({
    textWeek :{
        color : 'blue',
        fontSize : 11,
        flex:1,
        textAlign: 'center'
    }
})
```

And `DayItem.js` which displays a view and a text nested inside:

```js
import React from 'react'
import {View, StyleSheet,Text } from 'react-native'

export const DayItem = ({number})=>{
    return(
        <View style = {{borderStyle:'solid', borderColor:'black', borderWidth:1,
                        backgroundColor:'yellow', height:40, width:50,
                        marginTop:2, marginLeft:2, marginRight:2, marginBottom:2}}>
            <Text>{number}</Text>                
        </View>
    )
}
```

When I ran my code, I found this error:

> Invariant Violation: Nesting a View within Text is not currently supported.

But when I changed my code in `Calendar.js` into this:

```js
<View style = {{flex:14, borderStyle: 'solid', borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'yellow',
                                }}>
                    {element}

                </View>
```

The code ran very well. And when I removed the `<Text/>` element inside `<View/>` in `DayItem.js` and kept using `FlatList` the code ran well too, and it rendered very nicely. I wonder perhaps React Native doesn't support nesting `Text` inside `View` in `FlatList`. Is that true? If that true can anyone tell me how to render `<DayItem/>` block in a different way. I want them to look nicely like using the `FlatList`.

And also my React Native version is 0.59.8

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are passing `DayItem` as `number` in `renderDayItem`

```
const element = DayList.map(item => (<DayItem number = {item}></DayItem>) )


<FlatList data = {element} renderItem = {renderDayItem} keyExtractor = {keyExtract}

const renderDayItem = ({item})=> (
    <DayItem number = {item}></DayItem>
)
```

So your `DayItem` code will be something like

```
<View style = {{borderStyle:'solid', borderColor:'black', borderWidth:1,
                        backgroundColor:'yellow', height:40, width:50,
                        marginTop:2, marginLeft:2, marginRight:2, marginBottom:2}}>
            <Text><DayItem ...></Text>                
        </View>
```

I think you want to pass `DayList` as data instead of list of `DayItem`

```
<FlatList data = {DayList} renderItem = {renderDayItem} keyExtractor = {keyExtract}
```

Comment: After seeing your explanation I think this is the stupidest mistake I have made in my life. It's very simple but looks like I've messed it up. Anyway thank you very much !!